# grep filtering with both pattern and input file

Tags: linux, perl, sed, grep, csh

I have an input file which looks like:

```
$Interesting line
$Interesting line 2
#Also interesting line
Non interesting line - filter out
$another interesting line
Interesting line contains FiRsT pattern
Another non interesting line
Interesting line contains sec"o^nd pattern
#Interesting line
```

I have another pattern file, which contains patterns I would like to filter (notice that the pattern file may contain problematic chars - I would like to refer them as simple chars and not wildcard / regex):

```
FiRsT
sec"o^nd
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
$Interesting line
$Interesting line 2
#Also interesting line
$another interesting line
Interesting line contains FiRsT pattern
Interesting line contains sec"o^nd pattern
#Interesting line
```

That is, the following two lines were filtered out:

```
Non interesting line - filter out
Another non interesting line
```

More precisely, I would like to have in the result file all lines contain any string of the pattern file OR lines starts with # or $ (order is important).

I know how to filter the strings from the pattern file:

```
grep -F -f pattern_file.txt input_file.txt
```

and I know how to filter all lines start with $ and #:

```
grep '^\$\|^#' input_file.txt
```

But how should I do both? Is the only way is to write a short sub-script for that, or may I still use simple grep/sed/whatever standard linux commands?

Again, remember that:

- Order of lines is important and must match the original input file order.
- Pattern file may contain problematic chars, I would like to refer them as regular chars (and not wildcards / regex).

**Edit**: Consider the following case:

Input file contains also

```
Interesting line with ^third pattern
```

Pattern file contains

```
^third
```

Of course, I would like that line to be in the result file. That's why I cannot refer the pattern file without -F flag, and cannot just add ^\$ and ^# lines to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `awk`:

```
NR==FNR { pattern[NR]= $0; count++; next }
/^[$#]/ { print ; next }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if (index($0, pattern[i]) > 0) {
            print; next;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could process your pattern file and quote all regex meta-characters.

Comment: It works. However the performance are bad (which is critical, as my files are huge (e.g. 1000 lines in pattern file and 21 millions of lines in input file). I guess that preloading of the pattern file instead of using index function every iteration may improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could quote the special characters in your first pattern file and pass the second pattern file unaltered.

```
 grep -f <(perl -p -e "s#([\^\*])#\\\\\1#g" pattern_file.tx) -f extra_patterns.txt input_file.txt
```

This sample command will just quote `^` and `*`. It is easy to add other metacharacters if required.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it according to other's suggestions - by processing the pattern file and escaping any meta chars. Writing it down here as I found this to be the full and performant solution:

```
sed -e 's/\([\.\^\*\[\$\\]\)/\\\1/g' -e 's/]/\\\]/g'  pattern_file.txt > new_pattern_file.txt
echo '^\#' >> new_pattern_file.txt
echo '^\$' >> new_pattern_file.txt
```

Then I can use grep:

```
grep -f new_pattern_file.txt input_file.txt
```

Here are more details about lists of chars should be escaped:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32355/escaping-of-meta-characters-in-basic-extended-posix-regex-strings-in-grep